# Compiling C++ code with TensorFlow without Bazel

Tags: c++, tensorflow, compilation

I am looking to adapt TensorFlow and its ANN capabilities for my computational mechanics purposes where majority of my codes are in c++. Is it possible to compile in c++ without using Bazel while including TensorFlow .h files? If so, I would really appreciate an example (haven't be able to find any online so far). 
Thanks

Edit: I did but i am not able to follow. Let me provide an example and maybe we can go from there. I am using ubuntu 16.10, gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005, and Python 2.7.12+. I have installed bazel from source and also have cloned TF repository (~/Desktop/tensorflow). Taking a slightly modified example from (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide), i have in example.cc:

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  using namespace std;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  // Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
  auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f}});
  // Vector b = [3 5]
  auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f}});
  // v = Ab^T
  auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  ClientSession session(root);
  // Run and fetch v
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
  // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
  LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
  return 0;
  cout<<"compiled correctly!"<<endl;
}
```

It is located in ~/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/example. My BUILD file - also in ~/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/example - reads:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "example",
    srcs = ["example.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

I try to compile from ~/Desktop/tensorflow using:

```
bazel build tensorflow/cc/example/...
```

This is what i get:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/cc/example:example up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/example/example
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.381s, Critical Path: 0.00s
```

Then when i go to ~/Desktop/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/example and run:

```
./example
```

I get:

```
2017-07-27 09:58:39.906578: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-27 09:58:39.906628: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-27 09:58:39.906636: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-27 09:58:39.906641: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-27 09:58:39.906646: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-27 09:58:39.907751: I tensorflow/cc/example/example.cc:22] 19
-3
```

Any help would be much appreciate it as i'm trying to wrap my hands around this. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2412 ?

Comment: Please see edits. Following the link, i am not sure how to incorporate libtensorflow.so into what I am trying to do.

Comment: 32 bits ? That's not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow to build a c++ code built on tensorflow framework without using any building tool like Bazel etc.

1. Clone/download tensorflow from github from the below link.

   Since `pip install tensorflow` will only install tensorflow for python.

   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile
2. To run `your_code.cc` (The c++ file which you want to build, use `.cc` for c and c++, `.cpp` will not work for some reason)

   Place the .cc file and .pb file in tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/

   Edit the following lines in Makefile in vim editor 
   (tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile)

   ```
   BENCHMARK_NAME := $(BINDIR)benchmark
   ```

   Instead of benchmark, give the name of your executable

   ```
   BENCHMARK_SRCS := \
   tensorflow/core/util/reporter.cc \
   tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc \
   tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model_main.cc
   ```

   Remove these files and add you source codes (`.cc`) here.
3. Next Comment this line in the Makefile:

   ```
   all: $(LIB_PATH) $(BENCHMARK_NAME)
   ```

   and add the follwing line:

   ```
   all: $(BENCHMARK_NAME)
   ```
4. Next to run the make file go to the root directory (tesnroflow/) and type the following command.

   ```
   make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile
   ```
5. If you face any errors just type the following commands,

   ```
   export HOST_NSYNC_LIB=`/home/nivedita_s/Downloads/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_nsync.sh`
   export TARGET_NSYNC_LIB="$HOST_NSYNC_LIB"
   ```
6. If you have followed all the process properly then the executable will be created in this folder mentioned below,

   ```
   tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/
   ```
7. The output will be created in the name you specify for the executable.
   If `./executable_file` gave any library issue then follow the further steps (a and b).

   - `vim ~/.profile` to add this line at the end,

     ```
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path_to_the_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf/src/.libs
     ```
   - Run this command

     ```
     source ~/.profile
     ```

Now you should be able run your program in that terminal.

Comment: Why  tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/ path? Why not any custom path?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to tinker with your environment too much there are two possibilities. One is to compile the C++ API with Floop's [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project and install on your system. The other possibility is my packaging project [tensorflow_cpp_packaging](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging) to provide Debian packages for the C and C++ API of Tensorflow. Both projects use CMake (instead of Bazel) to support C++ compilation of your source files. Time to time, I compile the latest Tensorflow version, they are available in the [release](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging/releases) section for 64 bit CPU and Raspberry Pi.

From Tensorflow point of view, the advantage of tensorflow_cc that you can build GPU support if you want while my project can only use CPU for inference.

If you go with either project, I can still recommend [my short tutorial](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging#save-a-checkpoint-in-python-tflearn) what I wrote how to freeze a Tensorflow model in Python and load with either C or C++ API and use for inference.

Answer (score -1):

The most easiest way is to simply copy all necessary files to the local project:

```sh
cd /git/github.com/tensorflow
git clone git@github.com:tensorflow/tensorflow.git
# build TensorFlow once (tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so, tensorflow:libtensorflow.so)
cd project
mkdir tensorflow
cp /git/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-tensorflow/tensorflow/cc tensorflow/cc
cp /git/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/cc tensorflow
```

Having these files in place, a very basic CMakeLists.txt does the job:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(TensorFlow_ABI 0)
set(TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS "${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=${TensorFlow_ABI}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=${TensorFlow_ABI}" )


project( TFMyProject )

include_directories(SYSTEM "${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS}/external/nsync/public")
include_directories(SYSTEM ${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(SYSTEM ".")

add_executable (example example.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(example -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive "/git/github.com/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so" -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(example -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive "/git/github.com/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so" -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

Even these settings can be set using [a python script](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference).